# Using variable field name in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to create some filtering in my application where user will click on cell and filter table based on that cell value... I have this so far

```
int c = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
int r = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
string s = this.dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value.ToString();
string n = this.dataGridView1.Columns[c].DataPropertyName.ToString();

weblogEntities dbEntities = new weblogEntities();
this.Text = dbEntities.Database.Connection.ConnectionString.ToString();
var ds = dbEntities.tbl_weblog.Where(m => n == s).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

but my filtering is not working because of lambda expression. Can someone point me how to actually include right lambda in my linq?

Explanation:
What i'm trying to do is `(m=>m.field_name == value)` where `m.field_name` should be `n`, and i don't know what that is before i execute filter, and value parameter is `s`.

Comment: what should be the filter? As you have it if n == s then you get the whole table if not then you get nothing. What is the column where you want to filter?

Comment: I think you need to compare some property of "m".

Comment: Can you write in English what your where clause should be?, because it's not clear what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation):

```
var ds = dbEntities.tbl_weblog.Where(String.Format("{0} = {1}", n, s)).ToList();
```

Another way is building query expression. Here is an extension method which builds predicate expression for filtering source by some value of property by name:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
   string propertyName, object value)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
    var body = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(value));
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    return source.Where(expr);
}
```

And you can use it this way:

```
var ds = dbEntities.tbl_weblog.Where(n, s).ToList();
```

NOTE: Do not convert value to string in this case. If you have integer value, then you should pass it as integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look through your code clearly.

What this line

```
var ds = dbEntities.tbl_weblog.Where(m => n == s).ToList();
```

is effectively doing is

```
var b = n == s;
// this line will include all if n==s otherwise include none
var ds = dbEntities.tbl_weblog.Where(m => b).ToList();
```

Your `m` variable from your lambda expression isn't being checked against.

There's not enough information to give you any more hints I'm afraid. You may want to consider naming your variables to be more human-readable (e.g. `columnIndex` instead of `c`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this::

```
var ds = dbEntities.tbl_weblog.Where(m => n == s).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

May be this will be helpful.